# Materialize jQuery functions not working in Webpack application

Tags: webpack, materialize

I recently migrated my project from Meteor to Webpack and am experiencing errors when trying to use Materialize.css to build my UI. The custom materialize functions, such as `$(...).tooltip`, causes an Uncaught TypeError to be thrown in the console. This does not allow me to use Materialize in my app.

Anyone else experience these kinds of errors when trying to use Materialize in a webpack application? Any direction on how to solve these problems would be much appreciated. Thanks!

The code I use to load the Materialize module and its dependencies in the index.js at the root of the directory is below.

index.js:

```
import 'materialize-loader';
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css';
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = require('jquery');
import 'materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.js';
import 'materialize-css/js/init.js';
```

Comment: What is loaded after materialize? It seems another framework is loaded after it and overwrites the global $ namespace.

Answer (score 4):

Struggled  with the same issue. What you need to do is to make following modification in your webpack config:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");
```

in the options for exports add:

```
plugins: [
     new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: "jquery",
            jQuery: "jquery",
            "window.$": "jquery",
            "window.jQuery": "jquery"
    }),
```

Also, remove the following statements from index.js:

```
import 'materialize-loader';
window.jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = require('jquery');
import 'materialize-css/js/init.js';
```

Note: I tested this for webpack 4+; not sure if it'll work for other versions.

Plausible explanation: The js file for materialize plugin probably uses window.$ or window.jQuery for jquery methods and probably you have to give a global alias for the same in your webpack config.

Comment: Adding the definitions on `window.$` and `window.jQuery` fixed it for me. Thanks!